# python3 - TypeError: can't concat bytes to str

Tags: python-3.5, elf

Here's the code:

```
def flip_bytes(binary_f):
    i = random.randint(0, len(binary_f))
    c = chr(random.randint(0, 0xFF))
    return binary_f[:i] + c + binary_f[i+1:]

def copy_binary():
    with open("license", "rb") as orig_f, open("license_fuzz", "wb") as fuzz_f:
        fuzz_f.write(flip_bytes(orig_f.read()))
```

`license` is an ELF executable, when I run the script I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 30, in <module>
    copy_binary()
  File "parse.py", line 11, in copy_binary
    fuzz_f.write(flip_bytes(orig_f.read()))
  File "parse.py", line 7, in flip_bytes
    return binary_f[:i] + c + binary_f[i+1:]
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

How do I fix this?

(Here's the [whole script](https://pastebin.com/EB8zDitd) just in case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
c = chr(random.randint(0, 0xFF))
```

to:

```
c = bytes([random.randint(0, 0xFF)])
```

Python 3 has separate bytes and str types. According to the documentation, bytes is an immutable version of bytearray:

https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes

https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray

If you pass a number to the bytes/bytearray constructor, it will interpret it as an initial buffer size and not the initial value of a single byte. This is why you must pass it a list containing numeric values interpreted as the bytes (they must 0-255 inclusive or it will throw an exception).